# Accessing variable from parent object in go html template

Tags: templates, recursion, go

I have recursive go html templates for showing replies to a post, the top parent object contains a field called `Random` and a field called `Replies`, I recurse over the replies, which don't have the `Random` field, but I want to use that same `Random` field in each reply.

When I try this it only goes two replies deep (I assume because `$` only references the parent object and not the "top" parent object.

EDIT: More code. `thread` is the original object passed to the template, `thread.Replies` are looped over recursively, but don't contain the `thread.Random` string. I want to make the `thread.Random` string available globally to all the children without restructuring the structs.

```
type thread struct {
    Random string
    Body string
    Title string
    Replies []*reply
}

type reply struct {
    Body string
    Title string
    Replies []*reply
}
```

Template:

```
<html>                                                    
  <body>                                                  
  <div id="posts">
    <p>.Title</p>
    <p>.Body</p>                                        
    {{define "replies"}}                                  
    <ul>                                                  
      {{ range $key, $value := .Replies }}               
        <p>$value.Title</p>                               
        <p>$value.Body</p>                                
        <p>$.Random</p>                                   
        {{template "replies" . }}                         
        </li>                                             
      {{end}}                                             
    </ul>                                                 
    {{end}}                                               

  <div id="posts">                                        
    <div class="replyPost">{{ template "replies" .}}</div>
  </div>                                                  
  </body>                                                 
</html>
```

Comment: How do you define `Replies`? Is it a slice of slice or what? Please add minimum working `go` example.

Comment: `$` references whatever was passed to the template, which is what the template has access to. If the template needs access to something else, it must be reachable from `$` as a field. Objects do not have "parents".

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you want to access in a template must be passed to it. There is no such thing as "this struct originally was a field of some other struct and I want to magically access this other struct".

Comment: I didn't ask for "magic", I asked for logic. Is there a way to set the field of the child of the parent recursively based on the parents data? This shouldn't require "magic" . We're talking about scope.

Comment: @hermancain The question in your comment is totally different from the original one. Any just because you do not like the answer it still holds. No, absolutely impossible.